# RegularExpression Attribute Not Working as Expected

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Hi I have this code

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[.\\\\/:*?\" + "<>" + "|]?[\\\\/:*?\"<>|]*",
 ErrorMessage = "Title must not contain any special characters")]
```

I want it so the string is not able to have any special character in apart from spaces but I'm not sure why this isn't working?

EDIT:

To confirm, the form won't submit with the string input of: nospecialcharacters

The error message appeard regardless if there are special characters or not.

Comment: This isn't working on the client-side or server-side or both? Can you include some sample input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't really make sense of your current regex but bear in mind that this attribute specifies that the property must *match* the regular expression (not that it must *not* match it). So, if you don't want *any* special characters, you need to specify that the property matches the following pattern:

- Start of the string
- Word characters and spaces only
- End of the string

Something like this ought to do it:

```
"^[\w ]+$"
```

Add any other allowed characters (e.g. dashes) into the square brackets.

You may also be able to omit the `^` and `$` characters as I believe these are included implicitly; I find it's better to be explicit about these things, though.

Comment: @Tuga Not without the multiline specifier, no.

Answer (score 1):

I also wanted to make validation which would eliminate characters, which are not allowed in Windows file and folder names.

Since I use a language which uses some "special" characters, like **Š**,**Č** and **Ž**, the above answer did **not** work for me. The `"^[\w ]+$"` treats these letters like special characters.
After an extensive search I couldn't find the correct answer.

Finally I solved my problem like so:

```
 [RegularExpression(@"[^|\\/:*?\u0022<>|]+$", ErrorMessage = "Title must not contain any special characters")]
```

The `\u0022` represents **"**.

I had some problems forming this string. I tried so:

- `@"[^|\\/:*?\"<>|]+"` but the **"** ended my string in the middle
- `"[^|\\/:*?\"<>|]+"` but this ignored backslash **\**